# how to load ubuntu onto apsire 5810 laptop

Tags: aspire

I have download the Ubuntu os onto a dvd and tried to load it onot my Aspire 5810T laptop but it will not boot it from the dvd drive. I have changed the order on the boot menu and put cd/dvd rom drive at the top. When i restarted the laptop it tries to load the dvd but then starts with windows vista what am i doing wrong to get Ubuntu onto my laptop?

Comment: did you just copy the iso or did you burn it with a disk imager?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to boot via DVD try with a pendrive. Create bootable pendrives using Universal USB Installer.
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Also what did you burn on the disk, the iso or used a image burner?

Comment: The dvd has burned correctly it shows all the files as shown on the how to page

Comment: then try it with a pendrive!

Answer (score 0):

Try to browse the contents of your DVD in Windows. If you see nothing, this probably means a DVD failure... If you see only one file (such as "ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso"), it means that you've simply copied the .iso file, but not correctly wrote the disc image onto DVD. In that case, the following article will probably help you:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

A correctly written Ubuntu DVD contains the following folders and files in its root:

`.disk, boot, casper, dists, EFI, install, isolinux, pics, pool, preseed, autorun.inf, md5sum.txt, README.diskdefines, ubuntu, wubi.exe` (total 15 objects)

Comment: The dvd has burned correctly it shows all the files as shown on the how to page